# GraphQL resolver returns copies of last item of the list

Tags: list, graphql-js, express-graphql

While using graphql-js package in my Node.js program, I see the QueryRoot resolver that's meant to return a list of custom objects, returns a list with copies of last item of what it resolves.

```
const Person = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Person",
  description: "This represents Person type",
  fields: () => ({
    favorite_game: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    favorite_movie: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
  })
});

const QueryRootType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Schema",
  description: "Query Root",
  fields: () => ({
    persons: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(new GraphQLList(Person)),
      description: "List of persons",
      args: {
        input: {
          type: new GraphQLNonNull(Name)
        }
      },
      resolve: async (rootValue, input) => {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          getRESTPersonsByName(input, function(searchresults) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(searchresults));
            resolve(searchresults);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  })
});

const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: QueryRootType
});

module.exports = Schema;
```

The result is like below, which shows copies of the last person in the list of 5 persons resolved. I also verified this at the field level resolver, still seeing same person coming in. (The resolver function getRESTPersonsByName is receiving the results fine from underlying API call, as expected)

```
{
  data: 
  {
    persons : 
    [{
      "favorite_game" : "half life",
      "favorite_movie" : "life of pi"
     },
     {
      "favorite_game" : "half life",
      "favorite_movie" : "life of pi"
     },
     {
      "favorite_game" : "half life",
      "favorite_movie" : "life of pi"
     },
     {
      "favorite_game" : "half life",
      "favorite_movie" : "life of pi"
     },
     {
      "favorite_game" : "half life",
      "favorite_movie" : "life of pi"
    }]
  }
}
```

Function getRESTPersonsByName goes something like this -

```
function getRESTPersonsByName(input, callback) {
  let searchresults = [];
  let person1 = {favorite_game: "spider-man", favorite_movie: "spider-man"};
  let person2 = {favorite_game: "god of war", favorite_movie: "lord of the rings"};
  let person3 = {favorite_game: "forza horizon 4", favorite_movie: "fast and the furios"};
  let person4 = {favorite_game: "super mario", favorite_movie: "super mario bros"};
  let person5 = {favorite_game: "half life", favorite_movie: "life of pi"};
  searchresults.push(person1);
  searchresults.push(person2);
  searchresults.push(person3);
  searchresults.push(person4);
  searchresults.push(person5);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(searchresults));
  return callback(searchresults);
}
```

Comment: The issue is most likely with `getRESTPersonsByName` and not the code you've posted here. Please update your question to include that code as well.

Comment: I've added getRESTPersonsByName call. The console.log() calls, both in the resolver and the underlying function returns full list as expected.